# EditText going through the layout, when typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollbar, scrollview

I have a scrollview and in it 2 TextViews and EditText surrounded by ListView, What my problem is when i type through my softkeyboard into the EditText, the vertical bar doesn't scroll it automatically to Bottom but slightly upwards. I've tried searching through Stackoverflow but no avail. 
Please enlighten me.

**ScreenShot:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvyyrgxmfrwqb3b/Screenshot_2013-10-24-17-30-43.png

Here's the code of my schema:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".EditorActivity"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="-35px">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_day_edited"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/day_modified" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="25sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:includeFontPadding="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:**
Found a solution. I added

> `android:paddingBottom="15dp"`

in editText properties in layout.
Thanks All.

Comment: you have to scroll to that particular position whenever you tap your EditText,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I added

```
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
```

in editText properties in layout. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your manifest file.

```
           <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" .>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to scroll to particular position-

```
yourScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       yourScrollview.scrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
    }
});
```